# PHP: Abstract PDO Database. Performance Considerations

Tags: php, performance, design-patterns, pdo

I am building an abstraction layer over the DB in PHP.

I use PDO and everything works perfectly in a pure imperative script.

Now i want to swap this bunch of code (a web service API) to an OOP approach with MVC and i am trying to abstract the DB interface to have calls like (in a race db enviroinment) getRaceList(); or getRookieAthlets(); etc from and present them whereever else.

It would work perfectly if i would do something like this in the persistance class to be called

```
class Persistantance{

   //other methods

/**
 * return all races
 **/
public function getRaces(){

    $result = null;
    try {   
        $db = $this->connect(); //return a PDO object
        $query = "SELECT races.title, races.year, races.id FROM races;";
        //here use prepared statement statements if needed
        $result = $db->query($query);
        $races = array();
        foreach ($result as $record) {
            //here insert $record in $races
        }
        $result->closeCursor();

        $db = null;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        // Print PDOException message
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $races;
}
}

class View{
    public function viewRaces(){
        //...
        $races = $pers->getRaces();
        foreach($races as $race)
            printRecord($race);
        //...
    }
}
```

It would work, but just like $stmnt->fetchAll() its very memory intensive since it brings everything in memory. Db is pretty big, but due to impagination it's unlikely i'll get very big arrays, but i'd like to know a pattern to be as much as size-independent as possible.
On the other side if i build an iterator i'd complicate the Persistance interface a lot(i want to distribute the interface):

```
//from a view class
perist->a_query()
repeat untill null
    perist->fetch_last_query_next()
perist->close_conn()
```

Moreover it wouldn't be possible to perform more queries in parallel if not complicating even more the interface with multiple iterators method.

Comment: sounds a bit like premature optimization to me. if the approach works, stick with it. you can improve it once you find out it poses a problem. in any case, run a profiler to find out how it performs.

Comment: Yes i know its an overkill for the actual state of the things, and i'll probably stick with it, infact the question was intended to look at future.